# File Input: ignore any previous data

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to use logstash to extract metrics from my logs, and then send those metrics with statsdb.

Because statsdb sends "live data" there's no point reading old logs and send them. So I don't need logstash to read all the existing and available data when it restarts. I just want it to process what's appended to the files.

I tried to play with the settings it still reads all the data when:

```
input { 
  file
  {
      path => "./dbg*.log"
      sincedb_path => ""
      start_position => "end"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to skip the existing data when starting logstash ?

**UPDATE:**

I had a look at the bug report and I'm considering raising an issue with logstash.
I found those two that are relevant, but they don't seem to be resolved or working on windows:

- https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1196
- https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-721

Answer (score 0):

start_position refers to data within a single log file, so it isn't of any use re. older logs files.

If your logfiles have a naming format based on date, you should be able to exclude them from logstash using the exclude parameter and a wildcard pattern.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/file#exclude

If you files don't have a naming pattern, you could also just zip older files and then exclude *.gz

```
find ./ -mtime +1 | xargs -n1 gzip
```

will zip all files older than 1 day.

You may also want to consider managing the key string used by Redis. This will allow you to move the keys from Redis so that they don't get into Elasticsearch

http://www.nightbluefruit.com/blog/2014/03/managing-logstash-with-the-redis-client/

Comment: But the first option mean you have to change the logstash parameters file every day. And if you start logstash after the logs are generated you'll still have some old data to process.

Comment: My understanding of the user's issue is that this is a once in time requirement ie that they want to kick off logstash from a certain date and ignore data from before that date. Once logstash has processed a particular log, it won't check it again, so there would be no need to change the parameters every day.

Comment: Not really. We just want logstash to focus only on the newest data, every time we start it. Also you can tell logstash to exclude some files, but still it will read the old data in the files that are included.

Comment: Just modify your startup script to gzip any files older than 1 day before you start logstash, and then have an exclude for *.gz.

Comment: What about the old data for that day ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The input type is "file" so you have to deal with a file at a minimum. If you need to segregate log data at intervals greater than 1 day, you should be using logrotate to rotate your logfiles more than once per day.

start_position just tells logstash to start at either the beginning or the end of the file, but it still has to process the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try point the sincedb_path to **/dev/null**

For example:

```
input { 
    file
    {
        path => "./dbg*.log"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "end"
    }
}
```